# WSUS Replica sync updates with Microsoft Powershell

Tags: windows, windows-update

I'm trying to automate the configuration of a WSUS replica server.  I'm mostly there but can't configure the option to download files from Microsoft Update.

I want my replica to pull updates from Microsoft and not from the upstream server.  This is option in the UI:

[WSUS Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v69xQ.png)

Had a look through GetConfiguration(), been have been unable to find the option.  Also looked through the registry but can't see a key associated with the option.

Current code is:

```
Set-WsusServerSynchronization -UssServerName "SomeServer" -PortNumber 8530 -Replica

$WSUS = Get-Wsusserver
$WSUSConfig = $WSUS.GetConfiguration()
$WSUSConfig.ProxyName = $SomeProxy
$WSUSConfig.ProxyServerPort = $SomeProxy
$WSUSConfig.UseProxy = $True
$WSUSConfig.Save()

$Subscription = $WSUS.GetSubscription()
$Subscription.SynchronizeAutomatically = $true
$Subscription.SynchronizeAutomaticallyTimeOfDay = (New-TimeSpan -Hours 1)
$Subscription.NumberOfSynchronizationsPerDay = 1
$Subscription.Save()

Write-Host "Configured WSUS"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could have used the powershell cmdlet again and just done the below to configure it to sync from Microsoft

`Set-WsusServerSynchronization -SyncFromMU`

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. For anyone else: $WSUSConfig.GetContentFromMU = $True